# EFI application shell script

Tags: shell, uefi

I want to run my .efi application using EFI shell script, is it possible? If yes, then would the startup.nsh script run this script each time a system boots?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I see a bit of misunderstanding in you question. Yes you can lunch your efi application from nsh script but it has nothing to do with booting the system. The **NSH** as you can understand is a **shell script** and naturally it is executed only when **uefi shell** is executed. If you want your application to be lunched while system boots that is an absolutely different story. The mechanism for that is called Boot Options and it was described in a bit more details in that post ["How does UEFI work"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32223339/how-does-uefi-work/32255403).