# How to perform some security verification before booting operating system?

Tags: bootloader, bios, uefi

I have a bootable flash disk and it contains customized Ubunto, I want to pass the flash disk to an unknown person and it has some security issues. I want to be sure an unknown person couldn't change flash disk contents. hence I want to calculate hash of flash content and verify it on each boot and prevent booting OS if the verification failed or the hash goes mismatch.

for this purpose, I should do bootloader programming, I looking for UEFI programming but I found a few documents and videos, And also I do not know whether to select UEFI or BIOS.

so I would appreciate you if you could help me and provide a Comprehensive solution or suggest any other solution(except bootloader programming) for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going the wrong way. IMHO, the easiest way is to use the secure boot mechanism of UEFI. For that, you just have to sign your kernel and the modules that need to be protected.

[How to sign things for Secure Boot.](https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-sign-things-for-secure-boot)

Comment: Sorry, but that will not work OOTB.  Linux distributions use a shim which uses a MOK (Machine Owner Key) .   MOKList is the UEFI NVRAM variable which implements the MOK database.  The 'unknown person" will have to create MOKList on their hardware by enrolling a MOK before Secure Boot will work.